# Can't login with Wordpress openid anymore, receive "You do not own that identity."

Tags: support, openid, wordpress-se

I always log in with my wordpress account. In fact, I believe I am logged in with my Wordpress account at this moment, from my home server. But it goes automatigically, and I don't know where or whow I can track this (i.e, maybe I used another account?)

When trying to re-assign an openid from this account, it fails on all systems. My wordpress.com account exists (a dummy blog, http://abelsblog.wordpress.com) and my username there (metacarpus). Using "metacarpus.wordpress.com" as openid, I get to login (using anything else, like "abelsblog.wordpress.com fails). But when redirected back, it shows the messag:

> Wordpress.com
>   You do not own that identity.

Is this only me, or is it not possible anymore to login using wordpress.com accounts, or do the current DDos attacks on wp.com have anytthing to do with this?

Comment: Just a note: logging in with Google works correctly, possibly this is a bug only related to WordPress openid.

Comment: Problems of this nature are usually on the other end, and we can't do anything about it.

Comment: @Jon Unless "usually" doesn't apply here and the problem happens to be on this end. Unfortunately, that's a judgment I cannot make.

Comment: Note, for me, this was fixed by using http instead of https in the OpenID field on the Stack Exchange login page.